# How to set connection and socket timeout for default swagger android client

Tags: android, timeout, swagger, apache-commons-httpclient, swagger-2.0

I am using android api generated by default Swagger codegen (in Swagger Editor). The problem is that there is no any option, how to set connection timeout and socket timeout.

**Is there any elegant way to set timeout without any change in generated code? Or do I have to implement my own timer, which will terminate server call?**

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the default Android API client has any helper method to set the connection timeout.

I would suggest you to use the `okhttp-gson` HTTP library for Java instead (which is compatible with Android). Here is the command to generate Java client with the `okhttp-gson` library:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
-i modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.json \
-l java \
-o /var/tmp/java-okhttp-gson/ \
-D library=okhttp-gson
```

and it allows setting the HTTP connection timeout via the `setConnectTimeout` method in `ApiClient`

Comment: I've definitely found that default API does not have given option. OkHttp does. So I'm checking this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default connection timeout for OkHttp is 10 seconds. Can be modified by setting to Apiclient.

apiClient.setConnectTimeout(20_000);